# check that a module over polynomial ring is free

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, free-modules

I encountered this problem when I was doing practice exercises on Modules over PID:

Let $F$ be a field with characteristic $\neq 2$, 
and let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ with basis $\left\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3},v_{4} \right\}$. Make $V$ become an $F[x]$-module via

$$ x v_{1} = v_{2}, \quad xv_{2}= v_{1}, \quad xv_{3} =v_{4},
\quad \text{and}~ xv_{4} = -v_{3}+2v_{4}.
$$
**My question is:** Is $V$ a free/projective $F[x]$-module? If so, how may one check it?

I understand that a module over $F[x]$ is free if and only if it is torsion free, but this seems quite hard to verify.

Any help/hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: $V$ certainly can't be a free $F[x]$-module as it's a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$.

Comment: Rob Arthan has already given a nice answer, but you can see directly that $v_{1}$ is $(X^{2}-1)$-torsion, since $X^{2}v_{1} = Xv_{2} = v_{1}$.

Comment: Side note: Torsion free only implies free for finitely generated modules over a PID.  For example, $F(x)$ is torsion free but not free.